# Tableview not populating xcode

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have been creating an app in Xcode using tableviews. I added a new tableview activity and added the code.

I also have the files owner datasource and owner set to tableview. It does get the list it does have the list right before the code to add it to the table as my log does show all items.

I don't see what I am missing.

```
<code>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface BlogViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSMutableArray  *blogList;
}
@end

#import "BlogViewController.h"
#import "BlogController.h"

@implementation BlogViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor: [[UIColor alloc]     initWithRed:0.25 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0]];

    BlogController *blogs = [BlogController sharedManager];
    blogList = [blogs.testList mutableCopy];
    [self setTitle:@"Blogs"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return blogList.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", [blogList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    cell.textLabel.text = [blogList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:17];
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=0;
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;

    return cell;
}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *item = [blogList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGSize size = [item sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:17]
                   constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(220,CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    return size.height + 15;
}



-(NSMutableArray *) testList
{
    NSMutableArray *testList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [testList addObject: @"Key Blogs you should familiarize yourself with and potentially seek the attention of"];
    [testList addObject: @"Rapradar.com"];
    [testList addObject: @"Inflexwetrust.com"];
    [testList addObject: @"Globalgrind.com"];
    [testList addObject: @"2dopeboyz.com"];
    [testList addObject: @"Rap-up.com"];
    [testList addObject: @"Youheardthatnew.com"];
    [testList addObject: @"Hotnewhiphop.com"];
    [testList addObject: @"Rapgenius.com"];
    [testList addObject: @"Hiphopwired.com"];
    [testList addObject: @"Vladtv.com"];
    [testList addObject: @"Worldstarhiphop.com"];
    [testList addObject: @"Djbooth.net"];
    [testList addObject: @"Sohh.com"];
    [testList addObject: @"Hiphopdx.com"];
    [testList addObject: @"Allhiphop.com"];
    [testList addObject: @"Nahright.com"];
    [testList addObject: @"Pitchfork.com"];
    [testList addObject: @"Fader.com"];
    [testList addObject: @"Complex.com"];
    [testList addObject: @"Realtalkny.uproxx.com"];

    return testList;
}

</code
```

Comment: cursory glance, but this is a wall'o'code

Comment: did you debug the code to see the number of elements in the table? Are you sure the number of section is 0? Try to put 1

Answer (score 1):

numberOfSectionsInTableView: should probably return 1, not 0

Also you posted some code that looks like a test list to populate the tableview, but you appear to be mapping to BlogController's testList, which we don't see.  So there's no telling based on the code sample if there's actually anything to be loaded by the tableview.

Also we don't see the place in the code where the tableview's datasource is set to the instance of the BlogViewController - so it's impossible to tell if it's actually hooked up.

1) Change the numberOfSectionsInTableView: to return 1
2) Ensure there's really data
3) Put break points in the UITableViewDataSource methods to make sure they're being hit